# I have trouble installing gnupg on raspberry pi

Tags: compiling, gpg

I don't want to use the standard gpg version in raspbian which is almost 4 years old . I had to compile all the libraries manually . This worked fine but then when I compiled gpg it saied " libgcrypt too old need 1.7.0 have 1.6.4 " even tho I install libgcrypt 1.8.1 . So i uninstalled gpg and libgcrypt with " make uninstall " and compiled them again . With no success . I've tried to find a solution the last two days . There were some forum posts on the ubuntu forums , but they were not very helpful .

When I compild it the last time it gave out an error :

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:949: recipe for target 't-stringhelp' failed make[3]: *** [t-stringhelp] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/gnupg-2.2.1/common' Makefile:816: recipe for target 'all' failed make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/gnupg-2.2.1/common' Makefile:590: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/gnupg-2.2.1' Makefile:509: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: That's actually the *least* helpful part of the output.

Comment: Doesn’t Raspbian have the `gnupg2` package in version 2.1.18, which is ten months old?

Comment: mybe that's better https://pastebin.com/KD5nsn0q

Comment: No the gpg2 package is from 2013

Comment: What version of Raspbian are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: Raspbian
 Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie

Comment: Unless you require `Jessie`, you may want to change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ... [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)

Comment: My sources.list https://pastebin.com/s7bfYGHy

Comment: `Jessie` is old stable.  It shouldn't be used unless there is some special reason for it to remain in use.  At some point, updates will stop for `Jessie` ... you should change your `sources.list` to reflect the release of the new stable version of Raspbian which is currently, `Stretch` ... GNUPG 2.2 series is also the new stable for GNUPG.  The 2.1 series and prior end support at the end of Dec 2017.  ... **Update your `/etc/apt/sources.list`**

Comment: Will upgrading to stretch affect my applications ore even wipe some config file i potentially need ?

Comment: That's what test systems are for... Get a spare SD card and try it out.

Comment: my raspberry is not a test system . I need some applications on it . So I need to know what this Stretch update will erase and what not

Comment: @Richard, what RubberStamp is getting at is that even if you don’t have a test Pi, you can copy your SD card to another one, test the upgrade there and see if it suits you. If it doesn’t, switch back to the old SD card and you haven’t lost anything (apart from a little time). You’re the only person who can determine whether an upgrade is appropriate for you; we could tell you it would be, and I doubt Stretch removed anything you’d need, but I can’t *know* for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

From your comments, you are using the `oldstable` version of Raspbian.  You should be aware that the oldstable receives less frequent updates and is estimated to remain within the Debian security team's perview for about one year after the release of the next stable release.

See [Debian's wiki on oldstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable)

As such, Debian oldstable shouldn't be used unless there is some special reason for it to remain in use. All Raspbian users should change their `sources.list` to reflect the release of the new stable version of Raspbian which is currently, [Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)

GNUPG 2.2 series is also the new stable for GNUPG. The 2.1 series and prior end support at the end of Dec 2017.

See [GNUPG 2.2.0 Announcement](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2017q3/000413.html)

> The GnuPG team is pleased to announce the availability of a new release
>   of GnuPG: version 2.2.0.  See below for a list of new features and bug
>   fixes.  This release marks the start of a new long term support series
>   to replace the 2.0.x series which will reach end-of-life on 2017-12-31.

And [GNUPG 2.2.1 Announcement](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2017q3/000415.html)

> We are is pleased to announce the availability of a new GnuPG release:
>   version 2.2.1.  This is a maintenance release; see below for a list of
>   fixed bugs.

As far as the question: "Will upgrading to Stretch break things?"

I would suggest getting a second SD card, installing the new stable version of Raspbian on that new card, and copying over any personal applications and data.  This will allow you to test the new stable version while not disturbing your oldstable installation.

**Addendum**

Of course, this answer doesn't directly answer your question of "How do I build GNUPG?"

For a nice easy to follow answer to this question you can follow the instructions included on GNUPG's Webkey installation page:

[GNUPG Webkey with local build of new version GNUPG](https://www.gnupg.org/blog/20160830-web-key-service.html)

GNUPG Says:

> The easiest way to install the latest GnuPG version is to use Speedo, which downloads, verifies and builds all dependent packages. To do this first unpack the tarball:

```
$ tar xjf gnupg-2.1.15.tar.bz2
```

> On non GNU system you may need to use this instead:

```
$ zcat gnupg-2.1.15.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
```

> Then run:

```
$ make -f gnupg-2.1.15/build-aux/speedo.mk INSTALL_PREFIX=. \
    speedo_pkg_gnupg_configure='--enable-gpg2-is-gpg        \
      --disable-g13 --enable-wks-tools' native
```

> If you run into errors you are probably missing some development tools; install them and try again. If all succeeds you will notice a bunch of new directories below webkey's home directory:
>
> PLAY  bin  include  lib  libexec  sbin  share  swdb.lst  swdb.lst.sig
>   Optionally you may delete what is not anymore required:

```
$ rm -rf PLAY include lib swdb.*
```

> To make use of your new GnuPG installation you need to run this first (you should add it to webkey's .profile or .bashrc):

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd)/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

---

**End build instructions**

Of course, you will be playing with the latest version of GNUPG which is no longer 2.1.15

Comment: It somehow worked but now I have another issue :/ . I will make another post about that .